# 2 primary keys from different table as one foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to combine 2 primary keys from 2 different table into 1 foreign key in another table? I have a table named product_food with food_id as primary key and product_drinks with drink_id as primary key and then I want to combine food_id and drink_id as a foreign key in my orders table as product_ID? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways you can solve it, from the top of my head:

1. You get foods and drinks in the same table, using the same id, they may use different fields.
2. You make a table products with unique ids and make foods and drinks have a product id.
3. Make nullable foreign keys food_id, drink_id on the orders table and possibly add another field indicating which one are you gonna use.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use that as a primary key; define a different Product_Id primary key.

If you require uniqueness of the food-drink products, just add the two columns Food_Id and Drink_id to the products table, set them as foreign keys, and add a unique index on both of them, so that new products cannot be added, made of the same food-drink tuples.

Would that suffice your initial need?